# IndexError out of range in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement

Hi I am hoping you could help me in this python error that i could not solve

```
def remove_dots(string):
    lst = []

    for i in range(len(string)):
        lst.append(string[i])

    for i in range(len(lst)):

        if i <= len(lst): 

            if lst[i] == ".":
                lst.remove(lst[i])

            else:
                continue

    nstring = "".join(lst)

    return nstring
```

The Error:

```
        if lst[i] == ".":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And this is the call of the function:

```
print(remove_dots("maj.d"))
```

So if any one can help me and thank you

Comment: You meant to write your limit like this: `if i < len(lst):`

Comment: yes but i also want if the dot is at the end for it to be removed so ithiught that would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `i <= len(lst)` with `i < len(lst)` makes your code work, but it doesn't do what you might think it does. `lst.remove('.')` removes all dots from the list, so the whole loop is basically superfluous. You aren't supposed to remove elements from a list while iterating over it because it will change the length and you end up with index errors. You prevented that with the `if i < len(lst):` condition, but computing the length over and over for every iteration is very inefficient.

What you really want to do is something like this:

```py
def remove_dots(string):
    output = ""
    
    for char in string:
        if char != ".":
            output += char
    
    return output
```

This is a basic technique that you will use over and over while learning programming. However, if there is a builtin method that does the job, you should use it, so as others pointed out: just do `string.replace(".", "")`.

Answer (score 1):

Lenght should <.

```
def remove_dots(string):
    lst = []

    for i in range(len(string)):
        lst.append(string[i])

    for i in range(len(lst)):

        if i< len(lst): 

            if lst[i] == ".":
                lst.remove(lst[i])

            else:
                continue

    nstring = "".join(lst)

    return nstring

print(remove_dots("maj.d"))
```

Gives #

```
majd
```

### **Code correction**

You are over complicating solution. This can achieved easily with.

```
string = "maj.d"
string = string.replace(".", '')
print(string)
```

Also Gives #

```
majd
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second for-to-next loop `for i in range(len(lst)))` change it to `for i in range((len(lst))-1)` Its because your `lst` list index count is being exceeded due to that `try` using `-1` in the second for next loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use replace instead:

```
string = string.replace(".", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `lst.remove('.')` will remove all elements with value `'.'`, so length of list will change. If you want to remove all dots use `str.replace` function and replace dot with empty string:

```py
string.replace('.', '')
```